# how to find a string within a string using php

Tags: php, mysql

I am accessing a mysql database and displaying a column. in this column is a long string lets say its this:

```
<image identifier="540aa2ad-9a8d-454d-b915-605b884e76d5">
  <file><![CDATA[images/MV5BMTg5OTMxNzk4Nl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwOTk1MjAwNQ@@._V1._SY317_CR0,0,214,317_.jpg]]></file>
  <title/>
  <link/>
```

whatever lies between `<![CDATA[images/` and `.jpg]]></file>` will change on every row and i want to echo whatever lies between them pieces of code.

anyone help?

thanks

edit

so far i have:

```
function inStr ($needle, $haystack)
{
  $needlechars = strlen($needle); //gets the number of characters in our needle
  $i = 0;
  for($i=0; $i < strlen($haystack); $i++) //creates a loop for the number of characters in our haystack
  {
    if(substr($haystack, $i, $needlechars) == $needle) //checks to see if the needle is in this segment of the haystack
    {
      return TRUE; //if it is return true
    }
  }
  return FALSE; //if not, return false
}  
$img = '
SELECT *
FROM `item`
';
$result0 = mysql_query($img);

while ($row0 = mysql_fetch_array($result0)){

$haystack = $row0['elements'];
$needle = '<![CDATA[images/';
}

if(inStr($needle, $haystack))
{
  echo "string is present";
}
```

Comment: if the stuff that wraps around what you are searching for is consistent, substr with strpos is probably better.

Comment: please can you give an example, i havnt used strpos before.

Comment: I second regular expressions, though parsing it as an xml object is also an option.

Comment: @reece: minimally googling the function's name would yield the php docs -- complete with examples.

Comment: @denis i understand what the functions do, but i dont undestand how i can use them together to achieve what i want to achieve. which is why i asked on here to begin with. using strpos and substr so  far i have got (see edit)

Comment: strpos() is also an option, but preg_match would give you what's in between.

Comment: Do it in the SQL using SUBstring and LOCATE

Answer (score 1):

```
$cdata_part = preg_quote('<![CDATA[images/');
$end_part = preg_quote('.jpg]]></file>');

if (preg_match("#{$cdata_part}(.+?){$end_part}#", $text, $matches)) {
    echo $matches[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have XML, then it's easy:

```
<?php
$xml = <<<END
<image identifier="540aa2ad-9a8d-454d-b915-605b884e76d5">
  <file><![CDATA[images/MV5BMTg5OTMxNzk4Nl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwOTk1MjAwNQ@@._V1._SY317_CR0,0,214,317_.jpg]]></file>
  <title/>
  <link/>
</image>
END;

$file = (string) simplexml_load_string($xml)->file;

echo $file;
```

You may need to adjust the simplexml "path" a bit if you only supplied us with a partial text blob. You make it sound like there are several images within the XML, but as I don't know it's formed I cannot really tell you how to iterate over it.

Oh, and this will return the .jpg portion too, but removing an extension is as simple as `substr($file, 0, -4)` if you know it is .jpg.